# Multi-Label Classification RandomForestClassifier Scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was wondering which method is used by default for multi-label classification with RandomForest in scikit-learn? Haven't found any information in the documentation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "which method"?

Comment: What do you mean with which method. The method **is** RandomForestClassifier, used by the general fit/transform design. And the internals of these algorithms are normally referenced int he documentation. And the default-parameters are also documented. Just look into the APIs. You will in general always look at: "User guide"[here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#random-forests) + "API" [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html).

Comment: For instance problem transformation: binarize each prediction or use each label combination as single class

Comment: It's implicitly answered [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree-multioutput). DecisionTree is the basic building-block of RandomForest.